# How to use Vieta's Formula to find the roots of a quadratic

Tags: polynomials

How can I use Vieta's Formulas to find the roots of a quadratic?

Answer (score 3):

If we have the quadratic $x^2-sx+p=0$ then the roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$ will satisfy
\begin{eqnarray*}
 \alpha + \beta =s \\
  \alpha \beta =p. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
Little trick ...
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (\alpha - \beta)^2 = (\alpha + \beta)^2 - 4\alpha \beta =s^2-4p. \\
\end{eqnarray*}
So $\alpha - \beta =\sqrt{s^2-4p}$. Now add & subtract this to $\alpha + \beta =s$.

Answer (score 0):

For the quadratic $x^2 - a x + b$ with zeros $\alpha, \beta$ you have $a = \alpha +\beta$, $b =  \alpha \beta$. That is what one uses to factor it "on sight".